# C# FatalExecutionEngineError when executing CMD and a webrequest in backroundworkers

Tags: c#, process, webrequest, long-polling

I have a small programm which is running with .Net 4.5.2 on Windows7.
It can execute different processes on my computer (like starting CMD and stuff). It is also possible to execute these functions by a smartphone application.

To make this work, I have set up a singleton class which includes a `BackgroundWorker`. In the `do_Work` Method, a long polling mechanism is implemented. It will set up a request to a server via http and is waiting for the response or until a timeout occurs. It will setup the request again immediately after getting a response/timeout (TimeoutException will be ignored in an empty Catch-Block):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://xxxx.xxxx/xxxxx/res/jobs/" + Environment.MachineName + "?state=pending&wait=true");
request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

This works fine and functions can be executed on my computer immediately with the app.
On the other side, I am able to execute functions via the context menu of the program. These functions are also executed by a `BackgroundWorker`.

Because I am setting some EnvironmentVariables into the `Process`, the parameter `UseShellExecute` is set to `false`. (There are also processes without environment variables set, parameter `UseShellExecute` is `true` then):

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "call " + BuildNumberUtil.resolveDailyBuildAntFor2_4(this.sbSettings.SandboxPath) + "-f   antfile.xml deploy" + deployStatic);
processInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Remove("JBOSS_HOME");
processInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("JBOSS_HOME", WsSettings.JBossPath);
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

However, in a combination of the webrequest and a process with UseShellExceute=false, I am getting a FatalExecutionEngineError.

I broke down the problem to the following situation:

1. The webrequest is waiting for a response
2. I do start a process, which executes a cmd with UseShellExecute=false
3. A timeout occurs on the webrequest
4. TimeoutException is running in empty catch block and a new request is set up
5. executed Process ends
6. FatalExecutionEngineError is thrown immediately
7. CodeLine: `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();` is highlighted in debug mode

The problem does not exists when:

1. Process-Parameter `UseShellExecute` is set to `true` (no env variables set)
2. Webrequest ends with a valid reponse from the server (no Timeout)
3. Long polling is disabled / not running

I have built a workaround which is working pretty well (disabling webrequest before launching process and starting webrequest when process is finished).

Does anyone have any suggestion what exactly the problem is here? I want to understand why this FatalExecutionEngingeError is thrown to solve the problem and get rid of the workaround.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: The request.GetResponse() is a synchronous blocking method.  The kill is in an backgroundworker runninig async.  So you should Dispose the response before killing the Process.  I think the best solution is to impliment a backgroundwork Progress event to main thread.  Then dispose response in the Progress Report so you do not get any cross-threads. Or something similar.

Comment: Hi jdweng, thank's for the answer! But why doesn't this problem show up when I set "UseShellExecute" to true? All the code is running smoothly with various processes, as long as they have UseShellExecute set to true.

Comment: Do not know.  May be there is an exception handler in the shell.  You can check the Event Viewer to see if there are any errors when you run with a shell.